# efficient junit testing of graphs?

Tags: java, junit

For example, I have a graph below which shows me testing a depth first. I want to try and make my tests where I simply have a graph already made, then I make different test cases for that graph. But at the moment I seem to be making a new graph in each test method I make

```
@Test
void willItDepthFirst(){
        DepthFirstTraversal b = new DepthFirstTraversal();
        b.add(1);//add node
        b.add(0);
        b.add(2);
        b.add(3);
        b.add(4);
        b.add(0,1);//connect nodes with edges
        b.add(1,2);
        b.add(2,3);
        b.add(0,4);
        List<Integer> result = b.traverse();
        List<Integer> expected = Arrays.asList(0,1,4,2,3);

        assertEquals(expected, result);
}
```

This is kind of the idea of what I want:

```
@Test
void graphToBeTested(){
        DepthFirstTraversal b = new DepthFirstTraversal();
        b.add(1);//add node
        b.add(0);
        b.add(2);
        b.add(3);
        b.add(4);
        b.add(0,1);//connect nodes with edges
        b.add(1,2);
        b.add(2,3);
        b.add(0,4);

}

@Test
void testCase1(){
        List<Integer> result = graphToBeTested().traverse();
        List<Integer> expected = Arrays.asList(0,1,4,2,3);

        assertEquals(expected, result);

}
```

Comment: Either create the graph within your tests setup-function, or create it again on startup of every test by calling a comon method that only creates the graph. This is in no way special to tests. Just extract a method from common code and call it. Of course that helper-method itself is no test-method.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your tests don't need to modify the graph, you can save it in a static member and set it up in a `@BeforeAll` method:

```java
private static DepthFirstTraversal graph;

@BeforeAll
public static void setUpGraph() {
    graph = new DepthFirstTraversal();
    graph.add(1); //add node
    graph.add(0);
    graph.add(2);
    graph.add(3);
    graph.add(4);
    graph.add(0,1); //connect nodes with edges
    graph.add(1,2);
    graph.add(2,3);
    graph.add(0,4);
}

@Test
void testCase1(){
    List<Integer> result = graph.traverse();
    List<Integer> expected = Arrays.asList(0,1,4,2,3);

    assertEquals(expected, result);
}
```

Comment: you can still modify it in the single tests, I see nothing wrong with that

Comment: the dft objects cannot be referenced from a non-static context. therefore the traverse method cannot be resolved

Comment: @gazzo if method X modifies it, method Y will get an object it doesn't expect, and you may get unexpected results (e.g., test failures)

Comment: @foobar I don't understand that comment. Care to elaborate?